# Regular Expression in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

How can I get the quantity of reflector with this string using regular expression (answer should be 2):

```
13 x Ecobulb 7W 3000K B22 Non-Dim (CFL Replace) (front_entrance); 2 x Ecobulb 7W 3000K B22 Non-Dim (Reflector Replace) (front_hallway)
```

Comment: Hi, i tried the formula but the result is 13 which is the quantity of CFL, i need the quantity of the reflector which is 2. I tried this but it’s not working : (\d+)(.*Reflector.*$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ";")), "Reflector"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ";")), "\d+")*1, )))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
\s*(\d+)\s*x
```

and get the quantities with `\1`. Use some logic to associate the right quantity to the right product, and to calculate other stuff.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/IqglNd/1).

Comment: Tried that regex but the result is 13 which is the quantity of CFL. I need a quantity for a specific criteria like for example i need the quantity for Reflector. Tried this formula but it’s not working (\d+)(.*Reflector.*$)

Comment: but you have 2 reflector items - that is why I said "use some logic". Also, since you did not mention which tool you use to extract the data, I cannot give more information. On the regex101 link I provided, all instances of quantities are found, not only the first.

Comment: Oh sorry the second reflector is not included i pasted it twice

Comment: Does the list of parts change often? Does the list have an arbitrary number of parts, or always 2?

Comment: Yes the list of parts always change specially the cfl, sometimes there are 4 groups all cfl and no reflectors. That is why i need to have a code or criteria to get reflector quantity. My main goal for this is to put them on each column with header CFL and reflector with their corresponding quantity.

Comment: I think you cannot solve this problem using just one regex for all situations. Either you do it manually, or you need to use some other processing / calculations.